# EXT JS: How to hide the fourth tab of the item based on some if condition?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ext js and I am trying to hide the fourth tab on my screen based on certain entity condition. As, I have coded I am able to disable
(blur) the 4th Setting tab, but the hidden or hide() function is failing.

Basically, I want to hide the fourth tab in items Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg on certain condition. 
Any help would really appreciate, thanks in advance.

```js
var bsdataloded = false;
Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg = {
  id: 'PaymentSettingsPanel',
  title: getMsg('PaymentAdmin', 'PaymentSettingsHeader'),
  xtype: 'PaymentSettingsPanels',
  listeners: {
    activate: function() {
      if (!bsdataloded) {
        this.loadSettings();
        bsdataloded = true;

      }
    }
  }

}
var hidePaymentSettingcfg = false;
debugger;
if (Payment.EntitySettings &&
  Payment.EntSettings["EntSITE|Payment_SWitch"] === "Y") {
  Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg.disabled = true; //working
  // Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg.hidden  = true;// not working, even hide() not working
  hidePaymentSettingcfg = true;

}
init: function() {
  Ext.QuickTips.init();
  Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    expires: null
  }));

  app = new Payment.admin.AppContainer({
    id: 'main-panel',
    title: Payment.getMsg('PaymentAdmin', 'PaymentConfHeader'),
    el: 'bodydiv',
    border: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    defaults: {
      border: false
    },
    items: [{
      xtype: 'tabpanel',
      activeTab: 0,
      width: 500,
      deferredRender: false,
      hidden: false,
      defaults: {
        border: false
      },
      items: [
        Payment.PaymentItemCfg,
        Payment.PaymentPeriodCfg,
        Payment.PaymentTypeCfg,
        Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg
      ]
    }]
  });
  app.render();
}

};
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example to hide and show the tab based on if condition
i am hiding and showing the tab on checkbox checking but you can get your idea
i hope it will help you
[here is the Fiddle...](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t6n)

Comment: Thanks Salman, i tried even this method also before only. But I am not able to use the Ext.getCmp and it is telling that the value is undifined 
and error for Ext.getCmp('mytabpanel').getComponent('CNQR.admin.invcomp.BudgetSettingsCfg').tab.hide()
VM1090:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponent' of undefined.
Ext.getCmp is undefined. 
Even though I have declared the xtype and itemid for the last tab. 

id: mytabpanel
{xtype: 'tab', title: 'Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg',name: 'Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg', itemId: 'three'}

Comment: var hidePaymentSettingcfg = false;
    debugger;
    if (Payment.EntitySettings &&
      Payment.EntSettings["EntSITE|Payment_SWitch"] === "Y") {
      Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg.disabled = true; //working
      // Payment.PaymentSettingsCfg.hidden  = true;// not working, even hide() not working
      hidePaymentSettingcfg = true;
   change(hidePaymentSettingcfg);

    }

Comment: Added the changed below for some help.

Comment: if your tab is already hidden:true, then how he gonna find the tab to hide or show?

Comment: post your code where your tab is and i will figure it out that what you gonna have to do ;)

Comment: it started working and i added the working code below. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Added the logic to the listeners and it worked.

listeners : {
    afterrender : function(){

```
var testTab = this.getTabEl(3);
if (Payment.EntSettings["EntSITE|Payment_SWitch"] === "Y") {
    testTab.hide();
}

}
```

}